# How to stop Windows Calendar opening at startup?

Tags: windows-11, calendar, windows-calendar

I'm running Windows 11 Pro, and I upgraded to this from an earlier version (perhaps Windows 10? I can't recall).

Back in Windows 10, I had set my Windows Calendar app to automatically open at startup. I'm pretty sure this was a choice I made in the application settings.

Now, in Windows 11, there is no equivalent application setting I can toggle off. And Windows Calendar continues to open each time I log-in. I've tried looking in some standard places to disable this:

- The "Startup" folder.
- "Startup Apps" in system settings.
- MSConfig startup apps (not sure if that's different to above, anyway).
- The registry, under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

But there is no reference to Windows Calendar in any of these.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can stop this opening at log-in?

Comment: The only upgrade path from a previous version of Windows, was Windows 10, it wasn’t possible to upgrade any other version of Windows to Windows 11. Have you tried to Reset the Calendar application?

Comment: Also look in Autoruns (Microsoft SysInternals) to see if you can stop it from running at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion in the comments to try "Autoruns", I discovered I wasn't checking all of the startup folders.

I had reviewed only `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. However, I found the pesky shortcut in my user-specific folder:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Once I deleted that shortcut, Calendar no longer appeared at startup.